# Promises: how to get a response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am in the process of learning Node.js and am stuck on how I return the result of a mysql query as an API response. From what I have read so far, it appears as though I need to return a promise and resolve it, but I am not sure how I can return the data.

```
function get_free_count() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        var sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS number FROM users";
        conn.query(sql, function(err,result) {
            if(err) return reject(err);
            console.log(result[0].number);
            resolve(result[0].number);
        });
    });
}

app.get('/users/free/count', function(req,res) {
    var output;
    output = get_free_count().then(res.json(output));
});
```

I am getting stuck at the resolving and returning a response point. If I create a callback function inside the `then()` function, I am not going to be able to access the res object due to it being out of scope. So far, I haven't been able to find how to return the database value. What are the ways that I can return my free count as an API response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't wrap `conn.query` with a promise yourself, there are [libraries for that](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql)

Comment: Yes you should create a callback function ins the `then` call, because `then` requires one. No, `res` won't be out of scope due to the callback being a *closure*. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `output` inside `then` callback, also you should call `res.json` only when promise is resolved. Currently it's called immediately.

```
app.get('/users/free/count', (req, res) => {
  get_free_count().then(output => res.json(output));
});
```

Comment: Thanks alexmac for the fast response

Answer (score 0):

> If I create a callback function inside the then() function, I am not going to be able to access the res object due to it being out of scope.

That's where you're wrong - you **are** able to access `res` variable, because it still will be in the same scope (what I mean here is that the new, inner scope, can access all variables available in the old, outer scope). There's nothing wrong with the example below:

```
app.get('/users/free/count', function(req, res){
    // You don't actually need to store the "output" variable,
    // as it serves no real purpose in your example 
    var output;
    output = get_free_count().then(function (dbResult) {
        // req, res, output and dbResult are all valid variables in this scope
        // "dbResult" is equal to "result[0].number",
        // the resolution value of "get_free_count()" call
        res.json(dbResult);
    });
});
```

This is how closures in JavaScript work, you can read more about them [at MDN "Closures"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: For what reason did you leave `output` variable in your example?

Comment: There's no reason to leave it, but there's also no reason to remove it (as maybe OP wants to reuse it in a different fashion than presented in the example). I've added a comment about that variable being redundant.

Comment: I think the OP meant to use the name `output` for what you called `dbResult`.

Comment: @Bergi you might be right, but maybe let's wait for OP's response? I might clarify what ``dbResult`` is though...

Comment: Thanks mdziekon for correcting my misunderstanding of closure scope. I did mean to use output, the dbresult was understood. Final code is:

     get_data_count().then(function(output){
        res.json(output);
    });